# IP range in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I want to get access to a IP range with this net feature: 68.241.45.0/20 in .htaccess file and in RewriteCond. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^68.241.45.0/20
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) you can only do regular expression or lexicographic comparison. And since 68.241.45.0/20 is the range from 68.241.32.1–68.241.47.254, you could do this:

```
# regular expression comparison
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^68\.241\.(3[2-9]|4[0-7])\.\d+$

# lexicographic comparison
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^68\.241\.(\d+)\.\d+$
RewriteCond %1 >31
RewriteCond %1 <48
```

Answer (score 1):

RewriteCond uses regular expression on the second parameter. So you need to escape the dots (.) and use regex for the range.

`^68\.241\.[32|47]\.[1|2]?[0-9]+?`